# how to input list dynamic in python

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, infinite

```
1 ) input: 3 , return [1, 2, 3]
then continue 
2) input: 2, return [2, 4, 3]
then continue 
3) input: 6, return [3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
then continue 
4) input: 1, return [4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
then continue 
5) input: 1, return [5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

My code :

1)

```
list_num = [ int(i) for i in input('enter numbers divided by space ').split()]

print(list_num)
```

2. 

```
lst = []

# number of elemetns as input
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
 
# iterating till the range
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
 
    lst.append(ele) # adding the element
     
print(lst)

test_list1 = []
n2 = int(input("Enter number of elements2 : "))

for i2 in range(0, n2):
    ele2 = int(input())
 
    test_list1.append(ele2) # adding the element

print(test_list1)

res_list = [lst[i] + test_list1[i2] for i in range(len(lst))]

print(res_list)
```

but not dynamic

Comment: Please explain the logic and also add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code 2 seems to be doing a pair-wise list addition.
But the computation of your `res_list` is using the `i2` index, it should be just `i`.

Without the fix : `[4, 5]` plus `[0, 1]` gives `[5, 6]`.
With the fix : `[4, 5]` plus `[0, 1]` gives `[4, 6]`.